# Slack - Executing code (client) on click of Slack Message Title

Tags: slack-api

I have Slack message posted using postMessage & Attachment. It has Title and Title Link which opens the External URL. I wanted to capture the link click event when User click on it. Is it possible to wire click event and handle it?

Answer (score 1):

No. The Slack API does not provide any means to "capture" the click event and do anything else then open an external link in the browser.